# Binding Long property to String with replacement value

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've binded a Text property with Long Property

```
 text.textProperty().bind(newValue.referenceNumberProperty().asString());
```

There is the simply way to replace values <= 0 to  empty String ?.  I know that asString() method can take a parameter but I dont know how use it. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the use of the parameter of the `asString` method is concerned: It's meaning is explained in [the javadoc for `Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

There is no way to achieve the desired effect using a `asString` method alone. You could solve your problem by binding to

```
Bindings.when(newValue.referenceNumberProperty().greaterThan(0))
        .then(newValue.referenceNumberProperty().asString())
        .otherwise("")
```

or to

```
Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
   long val = newValue.getReferenceNumber();
   return val > 0 ? Long.toString(val) : "";
}, newValue.referenceNumberProperty())
```

though.

Comment: great. Thank you. it really help